# How to pass Anchor Attribute to Partial View call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Got a question and hopefully someone will answer.
I am working on an MVC Core project.

I have the following cshtml code:

```
@foreach (var idea in Model.Ideas){
    <a name="@idea.IdeaId" href="#">Interested</a>
}
```

This anchor will pop-up a modal, the modal contains a Partial View.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="FormInterested" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Ideation/IdeaInterestedForm.cshtml")
</div>
```

And my IdeaInterestedForm has a parameter for the "IdeaId", how do I pass the value of the anchor's name to @Html.Partial() call?

Answer (score 1):

There is more then one way ,

Basicly ,

You can call Partial View with parameter..

The parameters can be `Modal` or variable,actually be able to use model

```
@Html.Partial("_yourPartialViewName", Model)
```

or

```
@Html.Partial("_yourPartialViewName", new ViewDataDictionary { { "xId", someId } });
```

As a less used method than others ,

you can set value as a hidden field in the page and access it on the PartialView

```
 @Html.Hidden("xId",someInt)
```

or

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model=> model.xId, new { Value = someInt })
```

Geneated Html Code

```
<input value="5" id="xId" type="hidden">
```

use `JQuery` and read hidden value by field id

```
$("#xId").val();
```